# Div width not wrapping text in IE 11, Edge

Tags: html, css

I have text in a div that works fine in every browser, except for IE (of course).

The div has a set width, here's the css:

```
#header-text {
 color: #000;
 width: 29.4%;
 left: 48.5%;
 letter-spacing: -0.05em;
 text-align: left;
}
```

When I inspect the element the div has a width that is less than that of the text length, so the text should be wrapping. I've attached an image of how it looks/should be.

I've tried word break, word wrap, etc. but nothing is working.[image: Current/ Aim]

Outer div:

```
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
max-width: 1280px;
position: relative;
background-color: transparent;
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Can you show us HTML structure? Fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q6dL6kvm/ - works for me

Comment: I made a fiddle of the above, and it worked fine for me in IE and Chrome, but it won't work on the page. There must be something else, although I'll add in my question what the wrapper div css is like.

Comment: Depending on what you show  everything work great. 
Your issue can be due to by other element.
Still not enough info.

Comment: I just resolved it, it was a font-family I was using. I changed this to the regular version, then set a lighter font-weight.